# Location Marker Pin on Esri map is changing direction when we navigate. How to stop rotating of map pin

Tags: arcgis, esri

I am using a custom map marker icon which works well as expected. However as I navigate , the direction of the marker pin on map changes. I have tried changing the coarse symbol and heading symbol as well. But that doesn't work. Here's the screenshot.
[image: report]

How can I avoid this. Any help would be appreciated.